# Omnipay with 2Checkout Error

Tags: omnipay, 2checkout

I'm getting an error `Error Code:PE101`

The [docs](http://help.2checkout.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/Error-Code-PE101) say this;

> No value/invalid value for the "sid" parameter was passed in.

Well, I am using [Omnipay for 2Checkout](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-2checkout/blob/master/src/Gateway.php#L35-L38) that seems to be asking for the `AccountNumber` - not `sid`.

Looking at the [help](http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/What-are-the-parameters-for-2Checkout-s-Plug-and-Play-cart) they seem to be implying that `sid` **is the same** as the account number;

> sid – Your 2Checkout account number. (64 characters max)

So which is it? How do I set the sid there is no `setSid()` method!

At the moment, my code is;

```
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('TwoCheckout');
    $gateway->setAccountNumber($accountId);
    $gateway->setSecretWord($secretWord);

    $response = $gateway->purchase(array(
        'returnUrl' => $returnUrl . '?' . http_build_query($arguments),
        'cancelUrl' => $cancelUrl,
        'amount' => $payment->getAmount(),
        'description' => $description,
        'transactionId' => $paymentId
    ))->send();

    $result = $response->getRedirectData();
```

Result of a print_r($response->getData());

```
abort: (a)
always: ()
complete: ()
done: ()
error: ()
fail: ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (a)
overrideMimeType: (a)
pipe: ()
progress: ()
promise: (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: "Array↵(↵ [sid] => 901294374↵ [cart_order_id] => fmXkqNGlOshGspuxYXhL37eyLikXziuw↵ [merchant_order_id] => fmXkqNGlOshGspuxYXhL37eyLikXziuw↵ [total] => 61.00↵ [tco_currency] => ↵ [fixed] => Y↵ [skip_landing] => 1↵ [x_receipt_link_url] => https://checkout.example.dev/ecommerce/payment/complete?paymentId=fmXkqNGlOshGspuxYXhL37eyLikXziuw&pending=1&twocheckout=1↵)↵{"paymentId":"fmXkqNGlOshGspuxYXhL37eyLikXziuw","url":"\/ecommerce\/checkout\/postredirect?softwareVersion=7.66\u0026checkoutUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.2checkout.com%2Fcheckout%2Fpurchase\u0026paymentId=fmXkqNGlOshGspuxYXhL37eyLikXziuw"}"
setRequestHeader: (a,b)
state: ()
status: 200
statusCode: (a)
statusText: "OK"
success: ()
then: ()
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for leaving this as an 'answer', I'm unable to leave comments yet.

Omnipay-2checkout already passes the accountNumber parameter through to to 2checkout as 'sid' (See [here](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-2checkout/blob/master/src/Message/PurchaseRequest.php#L37)). Try calling `getData` on your request to see exactly what is being passed through to them:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('TwoCheckout');
$gateway->setAccountNumber($accountId);
$gateway->setSecretWord($secretWord);

$response = $gateway->purchase(array(
    'returnUrl' => $returnUrl . '?' . http_build_query($arguments),
    'cancelUrl' => $cancelUrl,
    'amount' => $payment->getAmount(),
    'description' => $description,
    'transactionId' => $paymentId
));

var_dump($response->getData());
```

It's also worth checking you are using the [correct](http://help.2checkout.com/articles/FAQ/Where-is-my-Seller-ID) account number.

Comment: Ok so is the value of `x_receipt_link_url` being passed to Omnipay? The result looks ok to me, can you see anything wrong? - I've updated my answer

Comment: @mike3875 While I've never used 2checkout in production `$response->getRedirectUrl()` should give you the url you need to send users to to enter their billing details.